# What is the syntax for directives in gcc asm command?

Tags: gcc, assembly, directive, inline-assembly

I'm trying to use `.ascii` directive in the gcc extended asm command but I keep getting compiler errors. What is the exact syntax for directives inside extended asm?

I tried the following options but none of the worked:

```
asm ("NOP;"
".ASCII ""ABC"""
);
```

I got "Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `/'"

```
asm ("NOP;"
".ASCII "ABC""
);
```

I got Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `/'"

```
asm ("NOP;"
.ASCII "ABC"
);
```

I got "error: expected ‘:’ or ‘)’ before ‘/’ token"

Comment: Show what you tried and what error you got. Anyway, the syntax can be found in the [assembler manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Ascii.html), but it's basically just `.ascii "text"`. Also, don't use it, you can just declare your text in C.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I edited my question in response to your comment

Comment: Think about the asm instruction the same way you would about printf.  If you want to printf `NOP;.ASCII "ABC"`, how do you do that?  To put quote marks inside the string, you need to escape them: `printf("NOP;.ASCII \"ABC\"");`.  Note that doing this inside an extended asm probably isn't going to do what you want.  The assembler isn't going to put the ascii string off in the "data" section, it's going to get put right in the stream of assembler instructions to get executed.  Executing "ABC" probably isn't going to give you the result you want.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for directives inside the asm is identical to writing GNU Assembler, so you can reference the GNU Assembler manual for the relevant syntax.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main (void)
{
  char *string;
  asm (".pushsection .rodata\n"
"0:\n"
"   .ascii \"Testing 1 2 3!\"\n"
"   .popsection\n"
"   mov $0b, %0\n":"=rm" (string));
  puts (string);
}
```

In the example we use an extended asm to copy the address of a string to a `char *` and then pass that to puts to print the string.

The string needs to be placed into the appropriate linker section, not just added to the current (usually the code section i.e. `.text`). So you begin by pushing the section you want the string stored to into the assembler's section stack. In this example I give it's the read only data section (`.rodata`) where most strings live. Then you pop the section off the section stack to get back to whatever section the compiler left you in, and do your operation with the string address. The trick is to use a local label like `0` to reference the string and let the assembler and linker compute the offset for you. This may require more work if you're PIE or PIC depending on how much more complicated your references become or if they require relocations.

Comment: Note that only C allows multi-line string literals.  In C++, you need to use ".pushsection .rodata\n0:\n\t"  / ".ascii ...\n\t" / "...".  This works and is good practice for C, too.

Comment: @PeterCordes : You probably meant back slash \ instead of forward slash /

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I was using those as line separators because <br> doesn't work in comments.  I forgot to put code-formatting around the parts that are literally in the C:  `".pushsection .rodata\n0:\n\t"` / `".ascii ...\n\t"` / `"..."`.  Normal C string-literal concatenation takes care of things across source lines.  You don't need to use `\ ` unless it's in a macro, so you shouldn't because it makes editing clunkier.

Comment: Shouldn't `string` be an output instead of an input (ie "=rm")?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd You are absolutely right. It should be input and "=rm" for the most optimal generated code with gcc at -O3.

Comment: One comment about the code, it won't work with 32-bit code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Changed movq to mov so it's not 32-bit and 64-bit compatible.