# how can I store string in memory dump

Tags: assembly, msp430

I'm in New Orleans in '[microcorruption.com](https://microcorruption.com)'.
[image]
Firstly, I wanted to reassembly the disassembled code.
but direct copy past into the online assembler didn't work.

So, I did some adjustments to the code.
After that it gave error in line-85 which is considered for storing the string "Enter the password to continue" under label **__do_nothing**

```
__do_nothing:
44e2:                 ret
;44e4 .strings:
44e4: "Enter the password to continue"
4503: "Invalid password; try again."
4520: "Access Granted!"
```

assembler is trying to evaluete '"Enter' as opcode.

But I want it to just record it into obj file.
So, what should I do?

I'll be pleased, thanks in advance.

[Whole code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sMjvFDknFuOS4CbZ7UGdiIo8VdhCZgvT)

Comment: The exact syntax depends on which assembler you're using.

Comment: Could you please give me the synonym of the 5-lines under label(__do_nothing) for your favorite msp430 assembler or msp430-gcc. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the syntax for directives in gcc asm command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091646/what-is-the-syntax-for-directives-in-gcc-asm-command)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to load and read all bytes from your dump and try the link below link to determine whether your byte is legit string or not
http://utf8checker.codeplex.com/

Comment: It has nothing to do with legit string, it is just an assembly code which has ANSI encoding.